# How to make the bar at the bottom of PriceGrabber.com

Tags: css, css-position

Newbie js question - I want to create a bar similar to the one at the bottom of the pricegrabber.com page:

http://www.pricegrabber.com/

Could anyone recommend terms I could search for to find a tutorial?  So far I have not had any luck.

Ethan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Javascript. Utilizing Firebug, one can determine the `<div>` is styled:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

That's it.

Comment: I am not a CSS guy.  Thanks, I didn't think it would be this simple.

Comment: Maybe also width: 100%; or left: 0; right: 0; and note that IE6 doesn't like position: fixed.